# searching using Apache Solr

Tags: java, solr

i need to work on Apache Solr for my project. previously i worked on lucene. can anybody get me d idea what is difference b/w these two nd when we should lucene and when we should Solr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got it was that SOLR provides an actual server, or can be deployed to an application server like Tomcat for instance. This makes it more standalone and distributable.

SOLR provides a few web services for adding/deleting/searching through it's search database. You can call these web services directly or use the [SOLRJ Jar](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)

So basically: SOLR is the boilerplate code around Lucene you would normally write yourself.

Comment: thanks for replying. i whnat to know should i need to write my own java classes for querying and searching.

Comment: As mentioned, you can use SolrJ which provides easy access to the search. It simply returns instances of [SolrDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/common/SolrDocument.html) which you can either map to your own model, or simply display

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is a library, and SOLR is a search engine built on top of Lucene.

SOLR provides a management interface via http, a search api via http, and an index update api via http.

SOLR is Lucene with a bit more added to make it easy to use without knowing anything about Java programming.

Comment: thanks for replying. i whnat to know should i need to write my own java classes for querying and searching.

Comment: You could treat SOLR as just another web service that provides a search capability. Of course, you would probably still write some classes, but they would not inherit from Lucene classes and your app would probably run in a different JVM as well.

Comment: By the way, if you run Linux, or can set up a Linux virtual machine, then it is easy to get a SOLR up and running for experimentation with Ubuntu. Either 'apt-get install solr-jetty' or 'apt-get install solr-tomcat6' depending on what appserver you like to use.